# Sync the Desktop App with WebSite

Tags: database, webserver, synchronization

HI all,

I had created a app(a Product to be sold to many users) which is almost complete, now I have a tough task to sync the app with the website, which will  be used to manage the data for all users. So it is quite obvious I will have to update the database that will reside on web server from the users desk through the app it self. Lets say I just want the users personal data to be stored on the DB on web server and anytime they update it in the app that should reflect on website as well(meaning the data on DB on webserver should be updated)

ANy ideas for doing this in best possible way, also this is just the example I will need to update heaps of data from users desk. I am already streching my hair thinking of managing data on server, can any one please advice here.

Thanks and Regards
Nirav

Answer (score 0):

You can write a update engine to upload users data to web server database.I had a exprience with Sql server replication on windwos XP and have some trouble and final I decided to develop a windows service that can do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response....Can you explore this a bit, I mean using windows service is fine..but what exactly it needs to do, I want it such that data will need to be updated almost each time user opens the app. So are you saying that this windows service should run in backend or like tray app or somehting similar and will update the web server data or it will be called at the updates from the app.

Comment: yes,This windows service must be always run in background and send data.This Windows service must detect changes for this may be you create another DB that keep changes or may be you save data in XML files.